# CumulusCI: Connect to org by specifying username and password right in command line

Tags: cumulusci

According to CumulusCI [docs](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connected_orgs.html) it is possible to connect to persistent org, but this requires opening web browser and typing your creds in SF log-in form.

Is there any way to provide username and password right into cci command line (despite how insecure it might seem at first glance)? E.g. I want to call cci command from our scheduled ci pipeline by providing creds from secret variables to trigger some data load into test sandbox over night.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your own connected app + JWT will work: follow the steps in https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/github_actions.html#connect-a-persistent-org

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to provide username and password right into cci command line (despite how insecure it might seem at first glance)?

No, there isn't. CumulusCI does not implement the Username-Password OAuth flow, and we won't implement it because it's completely insecure.

To connect to a persistent org, we recommend using the [JWT flow with a certificate](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/headless.html#register-persistent-orgs). This is the same approach used by Salesforce DX. It is secure, and while it's a bit of a pain to setup, it works reliably and indefinitely with no user interaction after that setup process.

Comment: Have you consider the case when people are working with some test sandboxes which do not have any critical information and are used purely for testing on dummy data being regularly refreshed etc.? Compromising access there wouldn't be an issue, since everyone knows creds there anyway. It would be way easier to be able to log in there by hardcoded login/password. BTW, even sfdx, you are referring to, have bunch of plugins which implement login/password authentication. I still do understand issue with security, but it's not always the case. You just need to know when it's approrpiate to use.

Comment: @wesaw If you are working interactively, you can use the Web Server flow by running `cci org connect`, which is fast and easy. We're never going to add support for username-password auth. Something like SFDX's auth URL strategy could be on the table, however.